How can I apply one time pad on a sound waveform file, assuming a same size key is distributed on both sides?
I am looking for a way to apply OTP on a sound waveform if possible.
Some questions emerged before I ever started.
Can I XOR a text file of the same size, with the waveform to produce a ciphertext that can  be then xored back to the original sound, using the same text file?
Is it as effective or is it better to OTP using a white noise waveform of the same length?
Is there a way to implement any of these ways suggested easily in Python3?

You can, of course, XOR two bytes together no matter what they represent. What is your goal here? Do you want to do with the encrypted waveform? Are you trying to securely encrypt the data, if so, why would the OTP be a text file instead of a file of random data?

Ok Roger that. We got a random data file and a waveform file. How can I XOR each byte using Python passing two files? Is there a ready method of a class or a function available or shall I do the trick doing something else?

Python has an XOR operator, ^. XORing two bytes is trivial. This is where explaining precisely which aspect is confounding you is useful.

So can I access ANY file and XOR it with another byte-to-byte iterating the contents and using just the ^ operator? Was that SO simple?
